# Can I put a Galaxy Note on Virgin Mobile (US)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note

I am thinking about getting the new Galaxy Note phone, but I want to put it on Virgin Mobile (US). Is this possible? If not does anyone know of any phone service like Virgin Mobile I can put the Galaxy Note on?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible. The Galaxy Note is a [GSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gsm) phone whereas [Virgin Mobile USA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_mobile#Virgin_Mobile_USA) is a [CDMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdma) network (it is a subsidiary of Sprint). The two are not compatible. In addition to this, CDMA carriers typically only activate phones that are specifically branded for their networks, so you can't even use a Sprint phone on Virgin unless you "know a guy" or find a *really* nice rep.

[The Galaxy Note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note) is quad-band GSM/UMTS, supporting the 850/900/1800/1900 MHz GSM bands and 850/900/1900/2100 MHz UMTS (3G) bands. If you get one that is not carrier locked then you can use it on AT&T, T-Mobile, and any smaller US carrier that uses their spectrum (Straight Talk, for example).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible now that Sprint is selling this phone with the radio that is needed for the Sprint network. I'm not sure how to get the store to activate the Note 2 yet. You may need to talk to them in person.

Answer (score 0):

me thinks it can be done because a Virgin Mobile phone rep told me that I could use a Verizon Note 3(Verizon 4G LTE phones are unlocked) but  wouldn't you just know when I got the Note 3 and went to activate on Virgin Mobile I was shot down!

AND I have a friend that has an old sim from Virgin Mobile and when she put that sim in the Verizon Note 3? In the settings of the phone(Apps > Settings > GENERAL > About phone > Status), it showed her phone number

Comment: Could you clarify your point, it's hard to understand what you mean. Are you saying it is possible? Or are you saying you have tried it and it wasn't successful?